# How do I get the INPUT element to call the underlying v-model setter for a computed property when v-model is an object?

Tags: vuejs2, getter-setter, html-input

When changing a value of an INPUT element, the setter is not called when the element v-model refers to an object.  Through the click method both versions of age change and the setter is called for both the simple variable and the object.  If I change the age through the input element, only the simple variable computed setter is called. What am I missing?

https://jsfiddle.net/sday/eywraw8t/411036/

```
<input type="text" v-model.number="age">
<input type="text" v-model.number="person.age">    

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    aperson:{age:25},
    iAge:25,
    text:""
  },
  computed: {
       age : {
          get () { 
              return this.iAge },
          set (value) {
              debug(this,"update detected through simple age variable: ");
              this.iAge=value;              
          },
        },
       person : {
          get () { 
              return this.aperson },
          set (value) { // <--- doesn't get called when changing through inputbox
              debug(this,"update detected through person object: ");
          },
        }
  },  
  methods: {
    click: function (e) {
        this.iAge++;
//        this.person.age++; // <--- this also works to increment
        this.$set(this.person, "age", this.person.age+1); // <-- thought maybe I had to do this for setter to be called during a change event
    },
  }
})
```